# Chrome extension Push messages : Unique ChannelId per user?

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I have a question regarding the push messages.
What I have so far is:
when the user installs the extension, im sending the ChannelId to my server and I store it there.
Whenever I want to send push messages(from my server side) to the users, I send a push message to each channelId i have stored.

My question is : 
Is the ChannelId unique for each user in my extension even after I update my extension/ uninstall and install it back?
Does the channelId ever changes?

If it changes, how can I manage the changed channelId and to connect it with the user?